# issue with PHP array and 500 error

Tags: php

So in my code I have:

```
 var_dump($poll);
```

which prints:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (9) {
    ["parent"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
        ["className"]=> string(5) "Venue"
        ["__type"]=> string(7) "Pointer"
        ["objectId"]=> string(10) "HRSCYpe2FK"
    }
    ["no"]=> int(0)
    ["updatedAt"]=> string(24) "2011-11-06T23:37:17.917Z"
    ["creator"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
        ["className"]=> string(5) "_User"
        ["__type"]=> string(7) "Pointer"
        ["objectId"]=> string(10) "96K81tdpM4"
    }
    ["createdAt"]=> string(24) "2011-11-06T23:37:14.591Z"
    ["yes"]=> int(1)
    ["objectId"]=> string(10) "U8ly32582W"
    ["question"]=> string(20) "Negozio conveniente?"
    ["reports"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (0) { }
}
```

and then I want to do:

```
var_dump($poll["parent"]["objectId"]);
```

but then it gives me a 500 internal server error. Any idea why this is?

**UPDATE:**
Pulling from the error log it says:

> **PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `$poll` variable is a `stdclass` in which case, you would access the properties like so

```
var_dump($poll->parent->objectId)
```

As for your 500 status, at a guess I'd say PHP is configured to trigger this for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're tying to do a var_dump on an object and not an array.

$poll->parent->objectId;

object :: object :: property